# Best way or platform to create a notifier

Tags: air, notifications

I'm attempting to build an notifier for a news website.. only function of the app will be to show notification when new news is added to the website. What will be the best platform for this function.

Air? Vb.net? or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think, it's a good idea to ask the users to install an application which is only for that site? Will they install? I don't think so.

Instead, you should use existing notification systems. See, ebay.com can notify you on various actions (overbid, won etc.) via IM: AOL, Windows Live, and Yahoo!. I think, Jabber (Google Talk) is missing.

If you use IM notification, it will run on all platforms, including smartphones.

Maybe, **Twitter** is also a good platform: it's public, you don't have to deal with registration, and you have some information about your subscribers.

Comment: wouldn't this require them to be added as a friend first?

Comment: In Twitter the user must "follow" the App's account. In case of IMs, the server should add the user as friend, which the user must response for by pressing an "okay" on the question sg like "confirm friendship with MyNewsApp", which appearing in his/her IM immediatelly or next login. It's just a click. Let's try EBay with Skype (costs nothing to create these accounts if you haven't any).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to hear other answers, this question is interesting.

I think Air may be the right choice, but: if you already know a little about different programming languages, why not use a different language for each platform? I think this is not the best choice for very big applications, but a notifier is a simple thing (just my opinion: sometimes I prefer that over forcing users to download Air in order to use that application).